# How do I alter a template file in a multishared child-site?

Tags: 7, theming

The site I am working on is the child-site (is that the correct terminology?) of a larger parent site.
The company I am working with uses the main, parent site as a sort of framework or base. It has a basic theme that the child sites use and build off from.

I want to alter the HTML of a pane element. The original template file for this is located back in a module directory of the parent site. There is no equivalent module or folder structure on the child-site.
I don't want to change the template file on the parent site as this would affect the other child-sites.

I've read up that you can copy the template and place it into the child-sites structure. Is this true?
If so, would I need to re-create the directory path to replicate that of the parent site's?
What's the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky since normally template files are located in the Theme's folder and not in a module's folder.

[image]

You could create a `/modules` folder under yourchildsite.com folder and copy the parent site module and paste it there. Then modify what you need.

I am not 100% sure this will work, but I hope it does.

Comment: Thanks. This seemed to work without needing to create a /modules directory as well.